# Facebook authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I have an application which displays canvas page, even though the user clicks "Dont allow" button in a request dialog. Here is my issue:

1. Load the page http://174.123.24.242/fb_leagle/fbhome.aspx
2. Login my application through facebook login page of my application.
3. Click on "Dont Allow" button in a request permission dialog.

In issue #3, if he clicks "Dont Allow" button it will also display the canvas page, and when I click the "BACK BUTTON" of the browser the next dialog appears. Actually I need to skip the canvas page from displaying when user clicks "Don't Allow" button and redirects to the next dialog.

This is my login URL of my application: pls review it and guide me where i need to change it.

> Blockquote

```
**https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=************&skip_api_login=1&display=page&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fleaglecases%2F%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D***************%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fapps.facebook.com%252Fleaglecases%252F%26display%3Dpage%26response_type%3Dcode%26canvas%3D1%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%252Cemail%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1**
```

pretty format of this url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=************
skip_api_login=1
display=page
cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fleaglecases%2F%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.
next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D***************%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fapps.facebook.com%252Fleaglecases%252F%26display%3Dpage%26response_type%3Dcode%26canvas%3D1%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%252Cemail%26from_login%3D1
rcount=1
```

Comment: @moguzalp Actually i have the correct sequence of url as u suggested , pls u review it once where i need to change....

Comment: URL IS:URL IS: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=************
&skip_api_login=1&display=page&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fleaglecases%2F%3F
error_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&next=http%3A%2%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D***************%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fapps.facebook.com%252Fleaglecases%252F%26display%3Dpage%26response_type%3Dcode%26canvas%3D1%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%252Cemail%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OAuth Dialog Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/), the user will be redirected to the original app-page.

> If the user clicks "Don't Allow", the browser will redirect to
>
> http://www.example.com/response?error=access_denied&
>   error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.

I suggest you use the `$_GET['error']` variable to recognize users that denied the request!
The different errors can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth/errors)

Comment: Hi,  i am using javascript sdk code for my application to proceed . how can i get by that way????

Comment: @Nirmala You could either write your own script to desect the window.location.href or use [this function](http://snipplr.com/view/19838/get-url-parameters/) to call the `error` as an index of an associative array the function created.